# How I can connect to Oracle from Perl?

Tags: perl, oracle, dbd

We have Oracle Server " Oracle Version: 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit".  I like to connect to this server with  Perl from my RHEL machine. I am able to connect via sqlplus successfully. I can use 32-bit or 64-bit Perl.  I have few questions.

Which files I should download from Oracle.com and  where should I install them?

What are the environment settings or path that  I should set?

What are the configuration changes or Makefile arguments changes  I should make to install DBD::Oracle module properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply `cpan DBD::Oracle` and saying yes to any dependencies that it wishes to install for you? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ignore the previous answer as it is woefully out of date.

All you need to download is the oracle "instant client" for Linux:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/linuxsoft.html

This gives you what you need to build the Perl module.

A quick google brought up the following for an install guide:
http://duberga.net/dbd_oracle_instantclient_linux/

(I'm sure there are others)

Comment: I should have mention this earlier. Simple installation should be easy. There are difficulties  connecting from a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Note: if you're using a DBD::Oracle that someone else has built for you, you only need the instantclient-basic package. If you're building DBD::Oracle yourself, you will also need to install the instantclient-sdk package before building DBD::Oracle (don't worry, it's very small)